# Rails custom route not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Feel like I'm doing this right, but apparently not.

I have a restful resource, Posts, with index, show, new, update, edit, etc actions in the controller. In routes, I have

```
resources :posts
```

I wanted to make the index action occur at the URL '/archive' instead of '/posts'

So I added this line in the routes.rb file, after the resources one:

```
match '/archive', to: "posts#index"
```

But when I click on a link to posts_path, it still goes to /post (though if I type in /archive as a url, it works -- not ideal, though). Confused. Could this have to do with my having installed friendly_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :posts, except: [:index]
get 'archive' => 'posts#index', as: :posts
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something like `match '/archive', :to => 'posts#index', :as => 'archived'`. Then you will have a new route to the tune of `archived_posts_path`. The method `posts_path` does not dynamically changed based on custom matchers. You can always run `rake routes` to see a list of routes for your site.